# Loading TIFF's in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to load TIFF's in an Android application.  However I cannot find a native Android loader for TIFF files.  Does anyone have some pointers?  I am reluctant to go down the JNI route as I feel sure there must be a simpler option!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is Google project going on this.
please check this: [Tiffonandroid](http://code.google.com/p/tiffonandroid/)

you can find all the related information here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my library that allow to choose some decode parameters for tiff (f.e. page for multipage tiff) https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory

Comment: Pulled some hairs while searching for a way to open my Tiffs to Bitmaps in Android until I found this library. Worked great for me! Thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

[Java Advanced Imaging (JAI)](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/iio.html) is the best solution. It has a decoder and encoder for TIFF files.

Comment: Unfortunately the Android doesn't have JAI, or imageio.  :(  If there is a way to sneak them on and make them work I'd like to know.