# How can I open a TIFF file in my Android application?  

Tags: android, tiff

How can I open a TIFF file in my Android application?

Comment: duplicate question - look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645810/loading-tiffs-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You can use my library, that allow to choose some parameters for opening TIFF https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory

Comment: Thank you very much. Your library is very usefull, especially for saving images to tiff.

Comment: Really useful, tested it with 60MB images and works ok, still pending to test it on bigger images but so far so good

Answer (score 1):

Open Source Google code project : [TiffViewer](http://code.google.com/p/tiffonandroid/source/browse/)

You can use it.